# How can I change the config file of the mongo running on ECS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I changed the mongod.conf.orig of the mongo running on ECS, but when I restart, the changes are gone.

Here's the details:

I have a mongodb running on ECS, it always crashes due to out of memory.
I have found the reason, I set the ECS memory to 8G, but because the mongo is running in a container, it detected a higher memory.

when I run `db.hostInfo()`
I got the memSizeMB higher than 16G.

It caused that when I run `db.serverStatus().wiredTiger.cache`
I got a "maximum bytes configured" higher than 8G

so I need to reduce the wiredTigerCacheSizeGB in config file.

I used the command line `copilot svc exec -c /bin/sh -n mongo` to connect to it.
Then I found a file named **mongod.conf.orig**.

I ran `apt-get install vim` to install vi and edit this file **mongod.conf.orig**.

But after I restart the mongo task, all my changes are gone. include the vi I just installed.

Did anyone meet the same problem? Any information will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ECS containers has ephemeral storage. In your case, you could create an [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) and mount it in a container, then share the configuration.

If you use CloudFormation, look at [mount points](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions-mountpoints.html).